# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSNumber' in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm getting error in the below code:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSNumber'

```
if let MId = (M as AnyObject).gid {
    if let id = MId {
       fetchvalue(id, limit: limit, delegate: delegate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Initializer+for+conditional+binding+must+have+Optional+type) before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `if let MId` succeeds then `MId` is non-optional (by the way please name variables with starting lowercase letter) so the second `if let` conditional binding is redundant and causes the error

```
if let MId = (M as AnyObject).gid {
    let id = MId 
    fetchvalue(id, limit: limit, delegate: delegate)
}
```

or even

```
if let id = (M as AnyObject).gid {
    fetchvalue(id, limit: limit, delegate: delegate)
}
```

And don't use ugly `... as AnyObject).foo` syntax use concrete static Swift types.